# How does javapoet process the AnnotationValue of the annotate attribute value

Tags: java, javapoet, annotation-processor

Methods to get custom annotations using AbstractProcessor
    Gets the attribute name and value of the annotation
    The attribute value is of type AnnotationValue
    Generate code with javapoet
    AnnotationSpec.Builder(xx). AddMember (String name, String format, Object... The args)
    Generated the wrong code:
    Such as: method (@ AnnotationName (value = "/" v1 / "/ v2"/"))
    Method (@annotationname (value={"v1","v2"}))
    Since there are several annotation attribute types, how do you tell which AnnotationValue is and generate the correct code with javapoet

```
AnnotationSpec.Builder builder = AnnotationSpec.builder(cc);
    //Gets the attributes and attribute values of the annotation
    //String:Attribute name of the annotation
    //Object:(AnnotationVale) Attribute value
    Map<String, Object> annoMap = annotationModel.getParams();
        if (annoMap != null) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> set = annoMap.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> m : set) {
            String memberName = m.getKey();
            Object values = m.getValue();
            builder.addMember(memberName, "$S", values);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error code currently generated by javapoet:

```
@RequestMapping( method = "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST", value = "\"/api\",\"/ll\"" ) class TestController$ { @RequestMapping( vv = "@com.seal.base.core.annotation.SealVar(\"1111\")", method = "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET", name = "name", value = "\"/register\",\"/api\"" )
```

Comment: Here is the error code currently generated by javapoet:
    @RequestMapping(
    method = "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST",
    value = "\"/api\",\"/ll\""
)
class TestController$ {
  @RequestMapping(
      vv = "@com.seal.base.core.annotation.SealVar(\"1111\")",
      method = "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET",
      name = "name",
      value = "\"/register\",\"/api\""
  )

Comment: Please display your error in your question rather than in comment

Comment: Did you try $L instead of $S?